# Cannot insert Third column of data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am noob in PL/SQL I just start learning and I want to create small peace of software that insert data from .CVS file to Oracle database. 
And I stuck in part where I grab data from .CVS file. 
I my CVS there are three column: Number_Policy,Contact, Agency
Number_Policy,Contact is catch success, but Agency can not be catched and I dont know why

```
declare 

   import_file text_io.file_type; 
   export_file text_io.file_type; 
   import_file_name varchar2(1000);
   export_file_name varchar2(1000);

   import_log_file text_io.file_type;
   import_log_file_name varchar2(1000);

   vec_importovano number;
   brojac number;
   brojac_redova number;
   linebuf varchar2(10000);

   p_rbr varchar2(20);
   p_polica varchar2(20);
   p_banka VARCHAR2(50);
   p_kontakt varchar2(20);

  kraj_fajla number;

begin
    brojac_redova:=0;

    import_file_name := :Global.Lokacija_prenosa||:import.naziv_fajla||:Global.Ekstenzija_prenosa;
    import_file := text_io.fopen(import_file_name,'r');

    delete from zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude where banka is not null;
    commit;

    kraj_fajla := 0;  
    while kraj_fajla = 0 loop
  begin 
    brojac_redova:=brojac_redova+1;
    text_io.get_line(import_file, linebuf);               

  if brojac_redova >= 2 then

    p_polica:=substr(linebuf, 1, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
  --    message(p_polica); 
    p_kontakt:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,2) - instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
    p_banka:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,2)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1);
  --    message(p_banka);   
    --p_kontakt:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,2) - instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
    --  message(p_kontakt);  


            /*
        p_rbr:=substr(linebuf, 1, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
     -- message(p_rbr);
        p_polica:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,2) - instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1); 
    --  message(p_polica);      
        p_banka:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,2)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1); 
          message(p_banka);
        p_kontakt:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,3)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,4) - instr(linebuf,';',1,3)-1);
          message(p_kontakt);
          */

         if vec_importovano = 0 then
        insert into ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE 
        (BROJ_POLICE,BROJ_PONUDE)       
         values(
         p_polica, 
         --p_rbr, 
         p_kontakt); 
        -- p_banka);            
            commit;
        end if;     
 end if;

     EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN kraj_fajla := 1;         
     end;

        end loop;  
          IF p_polica IS NOT NULL
   THEN
    update zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude set BROJ_POLICE=rownum;
            commit;          

     END IF;

    text_io.fclose(import_file);
      message ('Uspjesno zavrseno');

end;
```

As you can see from code there is error somewhere here

```
p_banka:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,2)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1);
  --    message(p_banka);
```

After I disable this column the problem is that column `p_polica` and `p_kontakt` can't be inserted into database. 
If anyone know where I made mistake I would be very thankful for any help.
[image]

Comment: In your `insert` statement you only specify 2 columns - the one to hold `p_banka` values does not exist. This would be a syntax error, have you edited the column list in sync with `values` list ?

Comment: The reason why is in insert statment only two column is that I test it if I can insert only these two column which is correct catche, since the thirth column can not be catched.

Comment: Have you checked for a 'not null' constraint on the third column ?

Comment: No, I have not checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `linebuf` has only two semicolons. This piece of code worked in my short test:

```
if instr(linebuf,';',1,3) > 0 then 
  p_banka := substr(linebuf, 
                    instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1, 
                    instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1);
else
  p_banka := substr(linebuf, 
                    instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1);
end if;
```

Comment: What is the logic here ?  If linebuf is bigger then 0  then take column p_banka ??

Comment: No, if it has third semicolon then use your formula, string between 2 and 3. If it has only two semicolons then use from second to the end of string.